# android.internal.telephony.xxx package support for cellular networks

Tags: telephony

Does Android support android.internal.telephony.xxx where xxx=3G WCDMA or CDMA.
I know it supports GSM. Would GSM package work with a 3G WCDMA Vendor RIL?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the radio debug logs using adb from a Nexus One connected to AT&T 3G network. The log showed that the GSM package was being used while in a 3G call. So it looks like a separate WCDMA package is not needed.